# Return PHP Array Values in Javascript Alert

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

in my Wordpress registration form, I want to return `$error` array in alert .

I've tried `console.log()` but it returns nothing, also with or without `JSON.stringify()` it returns an alert with only word : `true` inside it.

```
if($_POST){
    global $wpdb;

    //check no space  
    // ﻧﺘﺤﻘﻖ ﻣﻦ ﻋﺪﻡ ﻭﺟﻮﺩ ﻣﺴﺎﻓﺎﺕ

    $username = $wpdb -> escape($_POST['username']);
    // اﻟﻤﺴﺘﺨﺪﻡ
    $email =  $wpdb -> escape($_POST['email']); 
    // اﻻﻳﻤﻴﻞ
    $password = $wpdb -> escape($_POST['pass']);
    //اﻟﺒﺎﺳﻮﻭﺭﺩ
    $conpassword = $wpdb -> escape($_POST['passtwo']);
    //ﺗﺄﻛﻴﺪ اﻟﺒﺎﺳﻮﻭﺭﺩ


    $error = array(); // ﻟﺘﺨﺰﻳﻦ اﻟﺘﺤﺬﻳﺮاﺕ
    // حالة السترينج
    if(strpos($username," ") ==! false){ //true
        $error['username_space']= " اسم المستخدم يجب الا يحتوي على فراغات " ;

}
    // الحقل فارغ 
    if(empty($username)){
            $error['username_empty'] = " الحقل لا يمكن أن يترك فارغ " ; 

}     

    // التشابه
    if(username_exists($username)){
        $error['username_exis'] =" اسم المستخدم موجود بالفعل" ;
}    
    // الايميل غير صالح
    if (!is_email($email)){
        $error['email_notvalid'] =" البريد الالكتروني غير صالح " ;
}    
    // الايميل مستخدم  
    if(email_exists($email)){
        $error['email_exis'] = "البريد الالكتروني مستخدم بالفعل";
}    

    // اثنان من السترينجز تتطابق ام لا
    if(strcmp($password , $conpassword)!==0){
        $error ['passnotmatch'] = "ﺣﻘﻠﻲ ﻛﻠﻤﺔ اﻟﺴﺮ ﻻ ﻳﺘﻄﺎﺑﻘﺎ ";

    }

    if(count($error)==0){
        // انشاء مستخدم 
        wp_create_user($username,$password,$email);
        echo"ﺗﻢ اﻟﺘﺴﺠﻴﻞ ﺑﻨﺠﺎﺡ ";
         echo"<script> window.location = '".site_url()."/redafterreg/'</script>";
         exit();




    }else{
        $errorprint = print_r($error);

        $errorjs = json_encode($errorprint);
        echo "<script> alert( JSON.stringify($errorjs)) </script>";


    }
```

the output should be the strings inside `$error` array in an alert window. 
but it only returns `ture` as I mentioned before.  I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Per default, `print_r()` returns `true`. If you want to return the string instead of this value, you need to pass a boolean for the optional default parameter `$return`: `print_r($error, true);`

See [print_r documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

Comment: thanks for your help, but I have one more question: this returned the keys of `$error` and the values, is there a way to only return the values?

Comment: You can use `implode()` with new lines : `$errorprint = implode("\n", $error);` to have the list of error separated by new lines, and then in the javascript `alert($errorprint);` to print the full message.

Comment: I found `implode()` just an hour ago, but thank you very much this was a great help.